# Title Keywords in Context

Tags: code-golf, string, sorting

This challenge is based on a problem described in [*D. Parnas, On the criteria to be used in decomposing systems into modules*](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2979&context=compsci), and elaborated upon in [*J. Morris, Real Programming in Functional Languages*](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/other-authors/morris-real-programming.pdf).

Write a program or function which takes a list of book titles from `stdin` or as an argument, in a reasonable, convenient format for your language. For example,

```
Green Sleeves
Time Was Lost
```

or

```
("Green Sleeves";"Time Was Lost")
```

Return or print to `stdout` an alphabetized list of the keywords, showing their context within the original titles by enclosing each keyword in angle braces (`<` and `>`). As with input, output can be in a reasonable format which is convenient for your language- newline-separated lines, a list of strings, etc:

```
<Green> Sleeves
Time Was <Lost>
Green <Sleeves>
<Time> Was Lost
Time <Was> Lost
```

Titles will consist of a series of keywords separated by a single space. Keywords will contain only alphabetic characters. Keywords are to be sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Titles will be unique, and keywords will be unique within each title but the same keyword may exist in several titles. If a keyword exists in more than one title, the output should list each appearance *in an arbitrary order*. For example, given this input:

```
A Dugong
A Proboscis
```

A valid output would be either:

```
<A> Proboscis
<A> Dugong
A <Dugong>
A <Proboscis>
```

Or:

```
<A> Dugong
<A> Proboscis
A <Dugong>
A <Proboscis>
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)- the winner is the shortest solution in bytes. Standard loopholes are disallowed.

Comment: What about if the same keyword occurs more than once in a title? Should the occurrences be in order of appearance, or is arbitrary order permitted?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: from the spec, "Titles will be unique, and keywords will be unique within each title…"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>25</s> <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
VSsm,Rdcd\ QAN:HGjG"<>
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VSsm%2CRdcd%5C%20QAN%3AHGjG%22%3C%3E&input=%5B%22Green+Sleeves%22%2C%22Time+Was+Lost%22%5D&debug=0)

Takes input as an array of lines, like `["Green Sleeves","Time Was Lost"]`.

#### Explanation

```
VSsm,Rdcd\ QAN:HGjG"<>   implicit: Q = evaluated input

   m       Q                   map input lines:
       cd\                         split input line to words
    ,Rd                          replace each word by pair [word, entire line]
  s                          concatenate results for all input lines
 S                         sort the array of pairs lexicographically
V                        loop over the array
            AN             assign the word to G and the corresponding line to H
                 jG"<>       put the word between <>
              :HG          replace the word by the above in the line and print
```

Comment: [Looks buggy](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VSsm%2CRdcd%5C+QAN%3AHGjG%22%3C%3E&input=%5B%22Green+Sleeves%22%2C%22Time+Was+Lost%22%2C%22Time+Was+Time%22%5D&debug=0) - check the handling of title `Time Was Time`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Quoting from the OP, `keywords will be unique within each title`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), 55 bytes

Perhaps this could be made shorter, but I'm not sure how...

```
P+UqR £XqS m_+S+X) q', n £Xs1+XbS)rXs0,XbS),@"<{X}>")qR
```

#### How it works

```
P+UqR m@XqS m_+S+X) q', n m@Xs1+XbS)rXs0,XbS),@"<{X}>")qR
          // Implicit: U = input string, S = a space, P = empty string
UqR m@    // Split input at newlines, then map each item X to:
XqS m_    //  X split at spaces, with each item Z mapped to:
+S+X)     //   Z + a space + X.
P+   q',  // Parse the result as a string, and split at commas. Due to JS's default
          // array-to-string conversion (joining with commas), this flattens the array.
n         // Sort the result lexicographically.
m@Xs1+XbS // Map each item X to everything after the first space,
rXs0,XbS  // replacing the original keyword with
@"<{X}>"  // "<" + keyword + ">".
qR        // Join the result with newlines.
          // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, <s>41</s> <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
q~{:AS/{A1$/"<>"@**}/}%{'</1=}$p
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%7B%3AAS%2F%7BA1%24%2F%22%3C%3E%22%40**%7D%2F%7D%25%7B'%3C%2F1%3D%7D%24p&input=%5B%22Green%20Sleeves%22%20%22Time%20Was%20Lost%22%20%22A%20Dugong%22%20%22A%20Proboscis%22%5D)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 113 bytes

```
import Data.List
g l=[(m,h++('<':m++['>']):t)|(h,m:t)<-zip(inits l)$tails l]
f=map(unwords.snd).sort.(>>=g.words)
```

Usage example: `f ["Green Sleeves","Time Was Lost"]` -> `["<Green> Sleeves","Time Was <Lost>","Green <Sleeves>","<Time> Was Lost","Time <Was> Lost"]`.